# My words are my suffix, My eyes are my whole

Tags: riddle, rhyme

> I am currently my prefix.
>
> My words are my suffix.
>
> My lunges are my infix.
>
> My eyes are my whole.

Hint:

> Abbreviations.

Comment: Definitely 'lunges' and not 'lungs'? (Going by the body theme in last 2 lines...) Thanks :)

Comment: @Stiv Definitely 'lunges' and not 'lungs'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am currently my prefix.

> OP - Original Poster

My words are my suffix.

> EN - English

My lunges are my infix.

> PE - Physical Exersise

My eyes are my whole.

> OPEN

Comment: That was too hard

Comment: @Deepthinker101 Maybe, but I think "My eyes are my whole" is a big hint.